# Not getting 'Pending' payments in GetSellerPayments for half.com API

Tags: ebay-api

Posted this on the eBay API developer forum several weeks ago with no useful answers.  I am working with the GetSellerPayments API for half.com.  Getting an API response back on "Paid" payments works fine but I am looking to get "Pending" payments as documented here: [Half.com API GetSellerPayments API Documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerPayments.html) working as well.

Using API levels 913 thru 933 all same no joy behavior.

Simple request change of XML tag PaymentStatus from Paid to Pending:

```
    <PaymentStatus>Pending</PaymentStatus>
```

With "Paid" things work fine, with Pending no records found.  I have manually verified the seller account does in fact have pending payments at half.com.  And I have manually verified the date range for the payment period is correct and works at the half.com website.

Anyone have experience with this specific call on half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started working in API level 941